# Yoneda Lemma, newbie question. How is $\theta_{F,A}(\alpha) = \alpha_A(1_A)$ an element of the set $FA$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Part of Yoneda Lemma:

> There exists a bijective correspondence $\theta_{F,A} : \text{Nat}(\mathcal{A}(A,-), F) \xrightarrow{\simeq} FA$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is an arbitrary category, $A \in \text{Ob}(\mathcal{A})$, and $\mathcal{A}(A, -)$ is the representable functor, and $F: \mathcal{A} \to \text{Set}$ is a functor.
>   *Proof*: For a given natural transformation $\alpha : \mathcal{A}(A, -) \Rightarrow F$, we define $\theta_{F,A}(\alpha) = \alpha_A(1_A)$.

First of all how can they compose $\alpha_A$ with $1_A$ the two belonging to different categories, and two how is $\alpha_A (1_A)$ an element of the set $FA$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\alpha_A$ is a component of a natural transformation: by definition, it sends an element of $\text{Hom}(A, A)$ to an element of $F(A)$. More generally, the component $\alpha_B$ sends an element of $\text{Hom}(A, B)$ to an element of $F(B)$.

Comment: Oh, since $\alpha_A : \mathcal{A}(A, B) \to F(B)$, i see now.  I was thinking too generally.